# Is Error Trapping Data Returned by an Error-First Callback a Good Practice?

Tags: node.js, express

```
dataObject.query(err, data){
   if(!data){return;}
   else if(err){console.log("There is an error");}
   else{console.log(JSON.stringify(data));}
}
```

The author of *Getting MEAN with Mongo, Express, Angular, and Node* features a code segment in a API controller that is similar to the code above. Is the error trapping conducted in the first if statement for the "data" object necessary, considering the fact that the callback function already features an err object?

Answer (score 2):

If (!data) == true then it means there is no data received from the query. This is not an error, but just a query with 0 results (and as you can see no error is logged to console).

However the correct way to check is to flip the order between the first 2 conditions:

```
dataObject.query(err, data){
   if(err) { console.log("There is an error"); } // If there's an error from the query then log it.
   else if(!data) { console.log("There's no data"); } // If the result is empty (no data) then log that there's no data. (It is better to return a false value or some other indication that there was no result).
   else { console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); } // Finally, if there are results and no errors, log them as a string (pay attention that I've also fixed that function).
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip and I also edited the original post to correctly use the JSON.stringify() function. I assumed that the "data" object returning as empty would trigger an error and this error would be stored in the "err" object.

Comment: With pleasure. It depends on the implementation of the 'query' function, but the convention (which is also logical) is that an empty result set is not an error; Consider querying for a user named 'Joe'. If you don't have a user named 'Joe', is it an error with the query? or is it a valid and helpful answer that give you the option to continue the logic of the application from there?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you check error first:

```
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }
  }
```

Then you can check data, if it still can be missing. You can just short-circuit your function or call callback with a new error:

```
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }

    if (!data) {
      return callback(new Error('No data.')); // or callback(null, data) or something like that
    }

  }
```

Doing that in a different order makes no sense as in case of error `data` would be most likely missing.